# how to generate combinations given a starting point?

Tags: python

Let's say i want to generate all combinations of alphanumeric characters of length 2. Like so
`aa,ab,ac,...,az,aA,aB,...,aZ,a1,a2,...,a9,ba,bb,... so on`
and also i want to resume given a starting point. for example if i say `bb` the program should generate combinations that come after `bb`
like so 
`bb,bc,bd,.... so on`
is there a python library to do that? if not how can i do that? i'm looking for something like this

```py
k = 2 #length of the string in combination
s = 'bb' # starting point

generateCominations(s,k)
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use [permutation and combination](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/)

Comment: does it solve resuming problem?

Answer (score 0):

use [combination_with_replacement](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations_with_repetitions#Python)

try below code:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
import string

def generateCominations(s,k):
  alphnum=list(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
  combo=combinations_with_replacement(alphnum,k)
  result=[''.join(t) for t in combo]
  #print(result)
  return result[result.index(s):]

print (generateCominations('bb',2))
```

output:

```
['bb', 'bc', 'bd', 'be', 'bf', 'bg',..., '99']
```

However it's a combination so `'ab'`=`'ba'` so it return either `'ab'` or `'ba'` not both

if you want both then use [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)